# Websphere giving error particularly on 3 nodes only whereas other 3 nodes are working fine

Tags: java, spring, websphere, nodes, classnotfound

I have this websphere application installed and running on Windows with 6 nodes. Node A,B,C,D,E and F. When I hit the application on B,E and F it is working fine. But when I hit the application on Nodes A,C and D I am getting the below error on page.

> Error Page Exception
> SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.
>
> Original Exception:
> Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: Could not find required filter class - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.class
> Error Code: 500
> Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
> Error Stack:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
> at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:244)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:944)

As 3 nodes are working fine, I tried to uninstall and reinstall the ear file,cleared the cache and restarted, synced properly,checked the properties folder for all the 6 nodes(They are same),checked the jar files directory for all the 6 nodes(They are same), checked the java version,checked the directory permissions,checked the file size under installedApps directory. But I could not get a solution. Logs are showing the same error what I see on page and gives multiple classnofounderrors as mentioned below.

> [5/13/23 19:14:52:307 EDT] 000000c0 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.TextFieldTag
>
> //[5/13/23 19:14:54:311 EDT] 000000c0 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>
> [5/13/23 19:14:52:304 EDT] 000000c0 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AbstractClosingTag
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
>
> [5/13/23 19:14:52:293 EDT] 000000c0 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.IteratorTag
> at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:407)

I am really wondering how come it is working fine on 3 nodes and not working on other 3 nodes. Ear files is deployed on cluster,so the same ear file is deployed on all the 6 nodes.

Please help me to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: This feels like a classpath issue.  Possibly not having struts2 on the classpath, or possibly having two different versions of it. I'd check for .jar files or .zip files with struts in the name (and possibly peek inside the EAR file and see if it's in there too). Bit of a stab in the dark though.